# Can't switch AbstractRoutingDataSource without using @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions, datasource

I have a Spring-Boot project. As mentioned above, I want to use `AbstractRoutingDataSource` to switch *DataSouce*. I don't want to use `@Transactional` since no transactions are needed.
But when I transfer my method, it seems like which the `@Transactional` is being used, but when I test my method in unit test, it runs ok, I think it's strange because in unit-test, `@Transactional` shouldn't work.

```
public class DynamicDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

@Override
protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
    return DynamicContextHolder.peek();
}
```

}

The controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pipeline/analyze/{systemId}/{dbName}/{dbSchemaName}/{dbTableName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String pipelineAnalyze(@PathVariable("systemId") Long systemId, @PathVariable("dbName") String dbName, @PathVariable("dbSchemaName") String dbSchemaName, @PathVariable("dbTableName") String dbTableName) throws IOException {

    ETLServerAccessEntityInterface etlServerAccessEntity = etlServer.getETLServerAccessEntity();

   /* LOGGER.info("===etlServerAccessEntity.getAccessToken()===");
    LOGGER.info(etlServerAccessEntity.getAccessToken());
    LOGGER.info("isAlive=" + etlServer.isAlive());*/


    TableInfoMasterEntity tableInfoMaster = new TableInfoMasterEntity();
    TableInfoMasterEntityPk tableInfoMasterPk = new TableInfoMasterEntityPk();
    tableInfoMasterPk.setSystemId(systemId);
    tableInfoMasterPk.setDbName(dbName);
    tableInfoMasterPk.setDbSchemaName(dbSchemaName);
    tableInfoMasterPk.setDbTableName(dbTableName);
    tableInfoMaster.setId(tableInfoMasterPk);
    Example<TableInfoMasterEntity> exampleTableInfoMaster = Example.of(tableInfoMaster);


    List<TableInfoMasterEntity> filteredTableInfoMaster = tableInfoMasterService.findAll(exampleTableInfoMaster);
    System.out.println("filteredTableInfoMaster.size()=" + filteredTableInfoMaster.size());
    TableInfoMasterEntity tableInfoMasterEntity = filteredTableInfoMaster.get(0);
    pipelineRequirementAnalyzeService.analyze(tableInfoMasterEntity);


    return String.valueOf(pipelineRequirementAnalyzeService.toString());
}
```

the unit test

```
@Test
public void findByTemplateNameContaining() throws IOException {
    ETLServerAccessEntityInterface etlServerAccessEntity = etlServer.getETLServerAccessEntity();
    TableInfoMasterEntity tableInfoMaster = new TableInfoMasterEntity();
    TableInfoMasterEntityPk tableInfoMasterPk = new TableInfoMasterEntityPk();
    tableInfoMasterPk.setSystemId(1);
    tableInfoMasterPk.setDbName("DGRAMES");
    tableInfoMasterPk.setDbSchemaName("MESSERIES");
    tableInfoMasterPk.setDbTableName("TBLEMSACCESSORYSTATE_MAINTAIN");
    tableInfoMaster.setId(tableInfoMasterPk);
    Example<TableInfoMasterEntity> exampleTableInfoMaster = Example.of(tableInfoMaster);
    List<TableInfoMasterEntity> filteredTableInfoMaster = tableInfoMasterService.findAll(exampleTableInfoMaster);
    TableInfoMasterEntity tableInfoMasterEntity = filteredTableInfoMaster.get(0);
    pipelineRequirementAnalyzeService.analyze(tableInfoMasterEntity);
    System.out.println();
}
```

These two method are similar, they all transfers the `pipelineRequirementAnalyzeService.analyze(tableInfoMasterEntity);`
but the results are different. here is [the failure result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVB7U.png) and [the success result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Osz8.png).